# Getting a NullPointerException on a Firebase User that exists

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

This code was working yesterday, tried to run it again today and suddenly getting this error.

I can see on my firebase user database, that the user with the mail I'm trying to create, is getting created. And as my log states(pre defined from firebase): "The email address is already in use by another account". What I dont understand is, why I'm getting a Nullpointer and it can't find the user, and therefor not sending an verify email. How can it be null, and still say there is already an account with that email?

Relevant code:

```
//Method for signing up a new user
    public void signUp(String email, String pwd, Context context, Activity activity){
        //Listener which gives response when the createUser method has run
        mContext = context;
        mActivity = activity;
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd)
                .addOnCompleteListener(mActivity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                            if (user != null) {
                            user.sendEmailVerification()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Log.i(TAG, "Verification Email sent.");
                                                CreateNewUserActivity cna = new CreateNewUserActivity();
                                                cna.visibel();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            }

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Sign-up failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: " + task.getException());
                        }
                    }

                });
    }
```

More relevant code:

```
public void setupAuthStateListener(final MainActivity activity) {
        auth.addIdTokenListener(new FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIdTokenChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()){
                        auth.removeIdTokenListener(this);
                        firebaseHandler.loadDB();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Signed in from firebase");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MenuActivity.class);
                        activity.finish();
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        auth.signOut();
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Your email is not verified. Verify the email to log in.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i(TAG, "onIdTokenChanged: Email not verified");
                    }
                }else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Signed out of firebase");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Log:

```
2021-01-07 09:53:25.004 4117-4117/studios.kundby.fitnessapp I/AuthManager: onIdTokenChanged: Email not verified
2021-01-07 09:53:25.007 4117-4117/studios.kundby.fitnessapp I/AuthManager: onComplete: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzwg com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.zze()' on a null object reference
2021-01-07 09:53:25.007 4117-4117/studios.kundby.fitnessapp I/AuthManager: Signed out of firebase
2021-01-07 09:53:25.077 4117-4330/studios.kundby.fitnessapp I/chatty: uid=10080(studios.kundby.fitnessapp) RenderThread identical 1 line
2021-01-07 09:53:34.811 4117-4169/studios.kundby.fitnessapp W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2021-01-07 09:53:35.000 4117-4117/studios.kundby.fitnessapp I/AuthManager: onComplete: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: The email address is already in use by another account.
2021-01-07 09:53:36.497 4117-4169/studios.kundby.fitnessapp W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

Comment: Are you sure the user is logged-in correctly?

Comment: @AlexMamo I was logging out too soon. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the fact that I was logging out too soon.